# How can I give rank numbers to the sorted output?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

For example, if the input is:

```
Dog 100
Cat 200
Monkey 50
Elephant 20
```

I want the output to be:

```
1 Cat 200
2 Dog 100
3 Monkey 50
4 Elephant 20
```

I want to use the sort function to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 2):

In order to sort on the second element (`-k2`) of each line, and then to add the line nbr (`| nl`). The `-r` option is there to reverse order.

```
sort -k2 -rn file.txt | nl
```

which gives:

```
1   Cat 200
2   Dog 100
3   Monkey 50
4   Elephant 20
```